# How to calculate average values by group of other value type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id     day      action_type
1       0        upload     
1       0        upload 
1       0        upload 
1       1        upload 
1       1        upload 
2       0        upload 
2       0        upload 
2       1        upload
```

How to change my query to get table with unique days in column day and average number "upload" action_type among all id's. So desired result must look like this:

```
day     avg_num_action
0        2.5 
1        1.5
```

It is 2.5, because (3+2)/2 (3 uploads of id:1 and 2 uploads for id:2). same for 1.5

How to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Try `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.id, df.day).mean()
```

Comment: I think it should be `mean()` not `mean(1)`

Comment: @sammywemmy can you check again ?

Comment: did you edit it? doesn't look there were any changes. `id` is still the index, not `day`

Comment: @sammywemmy update, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```
df.groupby(['day', 'id']).count().groupby('day').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

With a groupby, and unstack:

```py
result = df.groupby(['id', 'day']).size().unstack('day').mean()
result 
day
0    2.5
1    1.5
dtype: float64
```

To match your expected output,add reset_index:

```py
result.reset_index(name = 'avg_num_action')
 
   day  avg_num_action
0    0             2.5
1    1             1.5
```